# C# Add security group to another security group

Tags: c#, windows, security, active-directory, ldap

```
        string ouString = projectBox.Text.ToString();
        string parentName = "LDAP://OU="+ouString+",OU=Clients,OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=net";
        DirectoryEntry parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry(parentName);
        DirectoryEntry newGroup = parentEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + ouString+"SecGroup", "group");
        newGroup.Properties["member"].Add("ExistingGroup");
        newGroup.CommitChanges();
        newGroup.Dispose();
        parentEntry.Dispose();
```

throws the exception:
The server is unwilling to process the request at newGroup.CommitChanges();  Any thoughts?

There is not a password issue, I believe it might have to do with no finding "ExistingGroup".  If i comment out newGroup.Properties["member"].Add("ExistingGroup"); it'll create the sec group just fine.  I'm trying to create a new Security group and make it a member of another group at the same time.

```
newGroup.Properties["member"].Add("CN=Clients Clients,OU=Clients,DC=domain,DC=net");
```

You have to fully qualify the groups location....

But this does the opposite.  It makes ExistingGroup a member of the newGroup, i want visa versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your domain password policies.

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80072035.htm

"One possibility is that you trying to enable or 'set' a user account.  The problem is that the account must have a password and none is provided. Another possibility is that your domain policy requires a complex password."

Comment: also i'm creating a security group, not a user.

Comment: Does the user executing the code in question have sufficient rights to create a group?

Comment: LoL, okay so the above adds that Existing Group as a member of the new Group, how do i flip it?

Comment: @Mike You have to commit the new group and then set the oldGroup's member attribute to point to the new group.  BTW, you can consider to use AccountManagement namespace in .NET 3.5, which is much easier.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.members.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I will back later with it and then maybe better code